# bash scripting not opening text editor

Tags: bash, if-statement, text, editor

following code executed in a terminal opens a text editor and displays loop.txt:

```
if [ -f loopy.txt ]; then
rm loopy.txt
touch loopy.txt
for i in $( seq 1 10)
do
echo $i line added >> loopy.txt
done
xdg-open loopy.txt
```

if I run it as a script, text editor does not open. Can anyone tell me why not?

Tks,
Robert

Comment: Try indent your code and please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Most of that code could be replaced with a single line: `printf "%d line added\n" $(seq 1 10) > loopy.txt`.

Comment: thanks that certainly shortens the code. Still does not answer my question, though

Answer (score 1):

Your script cannot run as it is.
You forgot the "fi" following the "if" clause.

```
if [ -f loopy.txt ]; then
   rm loopy.txt
   touch loopy.txt
fi # <----- you forgot that
for i in $( seq 1 10)
do
   echo $i line added >> loopy.txt
done
xdg-open loopy.txt
```